# How can you store user variables accessible by a rubygem?

Tags: ruby, variables, rubygems, arguments

I am in the process of creating a simple ruby gem to allow some github issue functionality in the terminal.

Overall it has been a great experience, but the biggest hurdle I am having (and haven't been able to find any useful information) is storing user variables that the gem can access and will be persistent.

For example when the gem first loads I ask them for username, token etc. I need to be able to store these settings somewhere that is accessible until the gem is uninstalled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look how the `gem` command itself stores settings. It's a `.gemrc` file in the home directory. A similar solution is what's most often used for command line tools that require user settings (another example `git` with `.gitconfig`).

Comment: Also, don't store passwords or data that allows access to the user's git-hub account in the file. If your code is available freely, and you store the user's login information in your own "." file, someone else could grab your code, use it to access that data from the file, and have easy access to commit havoc. *I* wouldn't be happy if someone did that to me or via code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

For command line gems, I've seen lots of them using a yml file to store user preference data, usually a dot file under root or usage directory. That's a preferred way IMO and I like that.

You need also set default preference in gem in case there is no user's settings.

Answer (score 0):

### Ways to Pass Data to a Ruby Program

Ruby gems, for the most part, can be thought of as specialized Ruby programs. As such, you have the same options for feeding input to a typical gem as you do for any other Ruby program:

1. Pass command-line arguments accessible via *ARGV*.
2. Pass environment variables accessible through the *ENV* hash.
3. Read in data from a file (or [*DATA*](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__END__)) by sourcing it or parsing it.
4. Hard-coding constants, globals, or magic variables.

You can use any of the above, in isolation or in combination. The choice is yours.

Comment: `ARGF` as well if you would rather open up an IO pipe.

Comment: @JordonBedwell The original question was about passing data into variables, but you're right: a file handle or I/O pipe can be stored in a variable, too, and may serve the same purpose in certain cases.

Comment: ARGF can be used to pass serialized data to an application, such as JSON, YAML, Ruby serialization (like dump), CSV and so much more.  This can then be rolled through and set accordingly with maps.